# PHP Parsear XML desde una url

Tags: php, xml

es la primera vez que parseo un XML desde PHP y tengo muchas dudas.

He escirto este codigo pero me da unos warning que no se si son normales:

```
$url = "http://...xml_obras.php";
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_string($url))
{
    echo "No se ha podido cargar el archivo";
} 
else 
{
    echo "El archivo se ha cargado correctamente";
}
```

y en la url si doy a ver código fuente me sale esto:

```
<obra>
      <ninventario>197</ninventario>
      <titulo>Blanca</titulo>
      <autor>ALBERS</autor>
      <fecha>1947</fecha>
</obra>
<obra>
      <ninventario>198</ninventario>
      <titulo>Alfa</titulo>
      <autor>Jose</autor>
      <fecha>1954</fecha>
</obra>
```

y sin dar a ver código fuente:

```
197 Blanca ALBERS 1947 198 Alfa Jose 1954
```

Estos son los warning:

> ```
> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in
> ```
>
> D:\wamp\www\cargaXML.php on line 4
>
> ```
> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
> ( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_string(): http://.../xml_obras.php in D:\wamp\www\cargaXML.php on line 4
> ```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿me podéis indicar como tengo que hacer el foreach para los insert? Muchisímas gracias

Comment: no, solo puse <?php y ?>, ¿Cómo debo añadir la etiqueta xml? por encima de la de php? <xml <?php ?> xml>?? eso en mi fichero cargaXML, en el fichero que me proporcionan no puedo modifciarlo, viene <obra> directamente

Comment: te hace falta el nodo principal, con eso solucionas el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu xml necesita una cabecera para que el navegador sepa que es xml , y tambien el primer nodo que los agrupe, te debe funcionar de la siguiente forma

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<obras>
  <obra>
    <ninventario>197</ninventario>
    <titulo>Blanca</titulo>
    <autor>ALBERS</autor>
    <fecha>1947</fecha>
  </obra>
  <obra>
    <ninventario>198</ninventario>
    <titulo>Alfa</titulo>
    <autor>Jose</autor>
    <fecha>1954</fecha>
  </obra>
</obras>
```

Comment: muchas gracias !!! puedes ponerme un ejemplo del foreach con un insert pot favor?? es que en todos los lados veo echo